# What is a "bot account" on github?

Tags: github

I am reading some [docs](https://github.com/benbalter/change_agent) that discuss how to authenticate on GitHub for a particular repo. They say "You'll likely want to use a bot account for this." (Docs are written by a Github employee). What is a bot account? How do I get one?

Comment: They are called [machine users](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Look at this section, "[User Accounts / What's the difference between user and organization accounts?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-s-the-difference-between-user-and-organization-accounts/)"

> User accounts are intended for humans, but you can give one to a
>   robot, such as a continuous integration bot, if necessary.

In other words, a "User account" can be for a "person" (the normal case), but it can also be used by an automated process (a "bot").

Which is precisely how Benbalter is using GitHub in the [Change Agent](https://github.com/benbalter/change_agent) project you cited above.

Q: How do I get one?

A: A "bot account" is just another Github user account.  You create it exactly as you would any other Github user account.

Answer (score 24):

In the [Account Requirements](https://docs.github.com/en/site-policy/github-terms/github-terms-of-service#3-account-requirements) section of github's Terms of Service there's a definition of a `machine account`:

> We do permit machine accounts:
>
> A machine account is an account set up
> by an individual human who accepts the Terms on behalf of the account,
> provides a valid email address, and is responsible for its actions. A
> machine account is used exclusively for performing automated tasks.
> Multiple users may direct the actions of a machine account, but the
> owner of the account is ultimately responsible for the machine's
> actions. You may maintain no more than one free machine account in
> addition to your free personal account.

Simply said, you can have your normal "human" account and an additional "machine" account for performing automated tasks.